# Control-A combination doesn't work in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, catalina, shortcut

My Control-A combination in terminal doesn't work.  Nevertheless, the Control-E combination still works. My macOS version is 10.15.4. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I also managed to determine that it shows menu bar instead for some reason

Comment: When you say not working do you think the software mapping of shortcuts has changed for only the one app or more than one app?

Comment: I assigned Contol A in Bartender to show all icons and forgot about it. I`m sorry for the stupid question. I am a newbie OS X User.

Comment: It's an awesome question! I love when a easy to ask question has a good answer. Even a full time person can't keep up with Apple - the software is so deep, so customizable. Thanks for asking and double thanks for self-answering. This will help people know it's possible to do this and when they do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in [Bartender](https://www.macbartender.com/), it was handling Control A.